# How to remove "Category: [category name]" from wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header, categories

I tried some solutions from another threads and it doesn't works for me.

[Screenshot](http://oi60.tinypic.com/33u323b.jpg)

I need remove that text from header in category. I would like it was only [category name].
Would anyone help me, please?

Comment: You have to edit your template. What template do you use?

Comment: Yes, the template's name is Masonic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Masonic Wordpress theme:

1. In theme editor edit file `extras.php`
2. Change line

   ```
   $masonic_header_title = single_cat_title('Category: ', FALSE);
   ```

   to this one

   ```
   $masonic_header_title = single_cat_title('', FALSE);
   ```
3. Save the changes and you are done